# How to run Mercurial (hg) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, mercurial

I want to checkout a repository using hg on Mac OS X.

I am getting this error:

```
$ hg clone -r release https://go.googlecode.com/hg/ $GOROOT
abort: Python support for SSL and HTTPS is not installed
```

And I check my hg and python location, but I forget how I installed hg and python on my computer.

```
$ which hg
/opt/local/bin/hg
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Can you please tell me how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this in your Terminal:

```
sudo port install py25-socket-ssl
```

Also, make sure you've got the latest versions of mercurial and Python.

Comment: ALso your path is mixed - you get Macports mercurial but Apple's python which could be the problem. Install from Macports python_select and choose python25 or python26

Comment: Thanks. I tried. $ sudo port pythong_select
Password:
Unrecognized action "pythong_select"
but i get 'unrecognized action' error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use MacPorts or Fink to install things that are either already on your system or aren't particularly difficult to build normally. Apple's Python and Ruby installations have a very specific structure which package managers tend to destroy.